# How to reconnect LVM disks?

Tags: 20.04, mount, lvm

I have a server running Ubuntu 18.04 and would like to move to 20.04. I do not want to upgrade but to reinstall from scratch to have a clean system.

All my services run under docker so the move will be very simple, the only issue I have is with disks.

I currently have three disks managed by LVM (in a RAID0 mode). They are independent of the system disk, just mounted as `/data`.

Once I reinstalled Ubuntu, what are the steps needed to bring back these disks to the system? Is it enough to just re-add

```
UUID=24bf43a5-d888-44f5-bb17-44d817916f1a /data ext4 defaults 0 2
```

to `/etc/fstab`? (my main point being whether this UUID is fixed, or should I look for it somewhere)

Answer (score 0):

Newer LVM will still detect older LVM and it should just all work. UUIDs of filesystems on LVs won't change. I have machines that have been using the same LVM setup for more than 10 years; in that time OS and underlying hardware changed multiple times.

When you reinstall just be careful not to do anything to the devices that are the PVs for your LVM.

To list all your PVs:

```
$ sudo pvs
```

So just be careful not to touch those. And a good idea to have backups just in case you do make a mistake.

Comment: *UUIDs of filesystems on LVs won't change* - does this mean that I can directly mount the LV the same way as before? Or is there something I have to do to "import" the information about this LV into the system?

Comment: Once they have been detected by LVM and activated then devoce nodes will exist in ```/dev/dm*``` and links to them in ```/dev/yourvgname/*```. The UUID is part of the filesystem which is content of the device, so it will be as before. So yes assuming LVM activates as before you should be able to find things by UUID as before so no changes to your ```/etc/fstab```.